# Get the aggregate column values in JSP when using group-by

Tags: sql, jsp, group-by

I have a problem when retrieving data from a SQL using JSP.

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select orderdate, 
                                              SUM(orderingcost) 
                                         from `shopping`.`order` 
                                     group by orderdate");
int count = 0;
//String

while (rs.next()) {
  //String orderdate = rs.getString("orderdate");
  //String orderingcost = rs.getString("orderingcost");
  System.out.println(count);
  count++;
}
```

I use group by statement to group some data.

However, I don't know how to get the data out when group by is applied.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

You need to alias the column:

```
select orderdate, SUM(orderingcost) orderingcost from `shopping`.`order` group by orderdate
```

Then you'll have a column named `orderingcost` in your resultset, and you can do:

```
double orderingcost = rs.getFloat("orderingcost") // probably need getFloat instead of string since it's a numeric value
```